# BeautifulSoup can't find class why and how

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse the HTML page of a popular music streaming web app with BeautifulSoup, I am using the find_all function to look for X css class.

Workflow looks like:

```
r = requests.get('URL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
soup.select("Tag", class_="Class name here")
```

The output is an empty list, which tells me it's not finding the class I'm looking for.

Here is the kicker: when I open the developer tools/HTML page source code, I can traverse the tree and find the class I am looking for.

Any ideas for why it's not being loaded. And can I load it into my python instance.

Thank you,

P.S. if any of my semantics/verbiage is incorrect please feel free to edit. I am not a webdev, just an enthusiast. >_<

Comment: Please include relevant HTML using snippet tool via [edit] and URL if possible as well as indication of expected results. Is your content js loaded and perhaps not available if using a fast retrieval method like requests?

Comment: @Qharr How can I snippet html source code, just the regular screen grab tool? With the URL its specific to each user instance AFAIK, the URL for me is: 'https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks' but that is different for each user I believe.

Comment: When you click [edit] button among the tools you will see an icon that looks like a document with <> on. That opens the snippet tool and you paste html top left. Alternatively, paste in the html into the question, highlight it, press Ctrl + K to format. The latter puts between code tags.

Comment: @Qharr, The file is too large, I am hosting it on github here: https://github.com/GregIven/HTML-example1.git [Please see the class tag for "tracklist-col" shows in the raw html code, but I cannot find this through bs4]

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve from that? Track names e.g. Take My Time Skinshape•Life & Lov ?

Comment: Thiose can be retrieved easily.

Comment: QHarr, so I tried a little experiement. I output the r.content to the console and saved it to a github file. The difference between the html code from source and the get request content is 157 v 28 kb. A massive difference. Could you explain whats happening here? And yes I am trying to get tracknames, however this is an exercise for myself, not just asking for an answer.

Comment: Is the content therefore dynamically loaded and you need a method like selenium? Have you tried using selenium?

Comment: @Qharr, I have not... I will look into this. Thank you for the pointer!